# Is there any difference between `runningFold` and `scan` methods in the Kotlin collections library?

Tags: kotlin

Comparing the pages for both methods `scan` and `runningFold` (from `kotlin.collections`), the two appear to be identical save for the name.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/scan.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/running-fold.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently there is no difference, check this out:

> runningFold() and runningReduce() are introduced as synonyms for
> scan() and scanReduce(). Such names are more consistent with the
> related functions fold() and reduce(). In the future, scan() will be
> available along with runningFold() since it’s a commonly known name
> for this operation. The experimental scanReduce(), however, will be
> deprecated and removed soon.

source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/05/1-4-m2-standard-library/